# Nginx: 564 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php"

Tags: docker, nginx, phpmyadmin, docker-container

I am trying to host phpmyadmin using a docker container on Nginx server.

I spun up a new container on the PhpMyAdmin app on port 8010. Locally I can get it it using `localhost:8010`

Now, I want to expose it to the outside word so I can browse it using adminusa.mydomain.com.

I create a new virtual host file called `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/adminusa.myadmin.com` with the following config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name adminusa.myadomain.com;

    return 301 https://adminusa.myadomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name adminusa.myadomain.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/certs/adminusa.myadomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/certs/adminusa.myadomain.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    access_log off;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/adminusa.myadomain.com-error.log;

    index index.html index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8010;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

When I browse the website using adminusa.mydomain.com, I get a white page. In the error logs I see the following error

> 3164#3164: *564 rewrite or internal
> redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php",
> client: 24.253.105.19, server: adminusa.mydomain.com, request: "GET
> /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "adminusa.mydomain.com"

What is causing this error?  How can I fix it?

Comment: remove the `try_files` statement. Using `try_files` and `proxy_pass` in the same `location` makes little sense anyway.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you! I removed `try_files` but still getting a blank white page. This time, I see a different message in the log file `*610 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: MyIpAddress, server: 0.0.0.0:443`